# How to query or access JSONStore data from native code in IBM Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

My app (iOS) will have a browser built in native code and the rest in Javascript using Worklight and there's a requirement to have a shared persistent database with encryption capability for both.

JSONStore seems to have all the functionality I need, but it's only available with Javascript. Is there any way I can access it in the native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature will be available in worklight 6.2, which is out now...

Answer (score 3):

Correct, JSONStore is only available in the hybrid (JavaScript) API. I am unable to commit to any features in upcoming releases, but I can say that have been a large number of people asking for pure native support in JSONStore. I will make sure your request gets capture as well.