# IBM Worklight - Is JSONStore supported in native iOS?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have read [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_08_JSONStore_-_The_client_side_JSON_based_database_overview.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406390/how-to-query-or-access-jsonstore-data-from-native-code-in-ibm-worklight) that, in Worlkight, JSONStore is available only for Hybrid applications.

Is it then correct to say that we can't use JSONStore in Native application for iOS? Are there any alternatives for it? What I guess is that we can use Core Data instead.

Comment: Please clear with your question. Please explain your requirement.

Comment: Why did I receive -1? Am I not clear with the above question? What do you need more?

Comment: I didn't down vote it.

Comment: I didn't point you but I wanted to know why was I down voted?

Comment: I have no idea buddy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. JSONStore does not yet support the native iOS and Android environments.

Quote:

> JSONStore is a JavaScript API for storing data inside hybrid
>   Worklight® applications. It is similar to technologies such as
>   LocalStorage, Indexed DB , Cordova Storage API, Cordova File API, and
>   IBM® Worklight Encrypted Cache. ...

See the comparison table in this link: [JSONStore features comparison](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_features.html).
You have some alternatives, but they are not as complete...

Core Data [does also sound like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883879/why-should-i-use-core-data-for-my-iphone-app) a (native) alternative.